# Using just the textview from SlackTextViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

I am writing a job management app that allows users to post responses to a job and I'd like to use a textview similar to the iMessage style. Essentially a textbox at the bottom of the view that when focused moves up to sit on top of the keybaord and moves the view content up aswell, but also grows as the text is being typed in.

I have come across SlackTextViewController which **exactly** suits my needs, however there is one issue. I already have the job view setup (Storyboard and Objective c) and all I'd like to do is use the textview portion of SlackTextViewController to write responses in, however SlackTextViewController ships with it's own tableview built in etc so whenever I use the textview, the table lays over the top of everything else on the view.

Is there anyway to 'break off' just the textview portion and use that in a pre-existing UIViewController? Or does anybody know of any alternatives that would achieve what I'm after?

Comment: I have tried using [super initWithScrollView:myScrollView] but the table is still rendered above and I can't see the content in my scrollview?